# Windows XP shortcut to open a html file in IE

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, shortcuts

Is there a way to create a shortcut that launches a html file in IE, instead of the default browser which is associated to the html file extension?

I'm trying to open my target https://CA01A0811:8333/ui/ which is my VM Server interface, but it doesn't work well in chrome, I need to use IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put in target of the shortcut:

```
iexplore.exe "https://ca01a0811:8333/ui/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new shortcut (Right Click -> New -> Shortcut), and in the 'Target' field put

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" [location]

where [location] is replaced by the address you specified.